# GWT - Disable KeyUpHandler in SuggestBox

Tags: gwt

Any thoughts on how one could disable KeyUpHandler in com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox?

(https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.java)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please correct me if I am wrong. Do you want to remove the auto suggest functionality of `SuggestBox`?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a KeyUpHandler, this method returns a HandlerRegistration object. When you no longer need this handler, you call:

```
myHandlerRegistration.removeHandler();
```